# How to fill TableView's Column with a values from an array

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have an `ObservableList` of instances of class `GameLogEntry`:

```
public class GameLogEntry {
    private int gameNumber;

    private int chosenStratA;
    private int chosenStratB;

    private Double[] scoresByB;
    private Double[] scoresByA;

    private double higherPrice;
    private double lowerPrice;
    private double averagePrice;

    private int maxIndex;
```

In my program I populate TableView's columns with values from this ObservableList.
[image]

My columns:

```
@FXML
    private TableColumn<GameLogEntry, String> colGameNum;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GameLogEntry, String> colChosenStratA;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GameLogEntry, String> colScoreByBOne;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GameLogEntry, String> colScoreByBTwo;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GameLogEntry, String> colChosenStratB;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GameLogEntry, String> colScoreByAOne;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GameLogEntry, String> colScoreByATwo;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GameLogEntry, String> colLowerPrice;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GameLogEntry, String> colHigherPrice;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<GameLogEntry, String> colAveragePrice;
```

I'm doing it like this in `initialize` method:

```
colGameNum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GameLogEntry, String>("gameNumber"));
colChosenStratA.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GameLogEntry, String>("chosenStratA"));
colChosenStratB.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GameLogEntry, String>("chosenStratB"));
colHigherPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GameLogEntry, String>("higherPrice"));
colLowerPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GameLogEntry, String>("lowerPrice"));
colAveragePrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<GameLogEntry, String>("averagePrice"));
```

But also I need to fill CS(B1), CS(B2), CS(A1) and CS(A2) columns.

CS(B1) should be filled with scoresByB[0],

CS(B2) - with scoresByB[1],

CS(A1) - with scoresByA[0],

CS(A2) - with scoresByA[1].

The question is - can I do it with the same simple methods like I did with other values? And if no, how can I do it in any other ways?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting data to JavaFX TableView without intermediate class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008352/inserting-data-to-javafx-tableview-without-intermediate-class)

Comment: @Sedrick I don't really understand how that question is related to mine. If you think it's about the same problem, could you please explain it to me in the context of my question?

Comment: You are right. Sorry wrong answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769723/populate-tableview-with-two-dimensional-array this is closer to waht y ou are asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply implement the factory yourself. You could create a helper method to avoid repeating the code:

```
static <S, T> Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<S, T>, ObservableValue<T>> createArrayValueFactory(Function<S, T[]> arrayExtractor, final int index) {
    if (index < 0) {
        return cd -> null;
    }
    return cd -> {
        T[] array = arrayExtractor.apply(cd.getValue());
        return array == null || array.length <= index ? null : new SimpleObjectProperty<>(array[index]);
    };
}
```

```
colScoreByBOne.setCellValueFactory(createArrayValueFactory(GameLogEntry::getScoresByB, 0));
colScoreByBTwo.setCellValueFactory(createArrayValueFactory(GameLogEntry::getScoresByB, 1));
colScoreByAOne.setCellValueFactory(createArrayValueFactory(GameLogEntry::getScoresByA, 0));
colScoreByATwo.setCellValueFactory(createArrayValueFactory(GameLogEntry::getScoresByA, 1));
```

For this to work however you need to change the types of the column to `TableColumn<GameLogEntry, Double>`. (In fact you should change ***all*** the value types for the columns, since not a single property is of type `String`; all properties are of type `Double` or `Integer`.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that String type was wrong. I had some doubts about it.

Comment: certainly possible but: if the individual elements of an array have some meaning, they should be modelled in an adapter to the log, not ad-hoc in a utility method

Comment: @kleopatra can you explain me what did you mean by that adapter thing? I'm quite new in Java.